# Show (popup) Dialog Form using Background Worker?

Tags: c#, multithreading, popup, backgroundworker, sleep

I must sleep my main thred 5 times, pausing 10 seconds each time for a certain task. 
Problem is that my main windows form freezes during the duration. So, I'd like to show a pop-up window wich is not frozen.

I've added a background worker to my main form:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
// ... how do I involve this?
}
```

When I push a button on my main form it does this:

```
BussyWindow bussyWindow = new BussyWindow();
bussyWindow.ShowDialog();
```

And then my main form goes into a loop for about 50 seconds.

I've tried:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.RunWorkerAsync(bussyWindow);
```

I'm stuck! What to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another form if you are using BackgroundWorker,try this:

```
 BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // do your work here
    }
```

Your work will be done asynchronously..

Comment: Ok thanks! But incase I would like another form, to display some heavy output (takes a lot of space, cleaner design). Where do I declare the new form and activate it?

Comment: I solved it! I was so dumb! It was just to call this backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();